# JavaScript floating point sum issue

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

Why JS show 25.1+61.7+13.2 = 100.00000000000001 ? Its fixed if you just change the position of the number like 13.2+25.1+61.7 = 100. Can anyone explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using floating point arithmetic.
[Here is an explanation of what is happening.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript uses IEEE 754 floating point math, which is a base-2 floating point format. There are many many values that cannot be represented exactly in that format, and specifically among them are decimal fractions like `x.7`.

It's not a **compiler** issue. It's an issue with the fundamental way that JavaScript represents real numbers. Many other languages would have the exact same problem.

Computers don't handle real numbers in a rigorous way, generally.